# Is there a possibility to call a method from the internal visualisation?

Tags: twincat

I want to call the method directly from the internal visualisation instad of change a variable and call the method every cycle

I have tried different inputconfiguration also run st code

[Errormessage onlineview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS6Mt.png)

[Method content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tL6r.png)

[Button config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdWP2.png)

Comment: Now it works. A visualmanger was missing

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you need to execute the methods in a button event,like the picture.

[Property of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDkn6.png)

You mentioned, you already tried to execute ST-Code in the visu. Could you please share some code, what you want to execute and how you linked?

Comment: Thx for your respond
I ve tried your proposal but I got an error:
"Error  The input action Execute ST-Code has statements which are no assignments. This feature is only supported for the target visualization"

Just added a method to Main prog and want call from the internal visu 
MAIN.M_SetGVL()

Just a test to figure out if its working

Comment: Could you please create some screeshot of your visualization part of your project (from the visu manager and the sub items.)?

Comment: Added some screenshots